# Complex Numbers where $z_1 = x + iy$ and $z_2 = a + ib$ with $z_1 = z_2$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need a little assistance in straightening out something fairly simple. I am over analyzing things I think and I just need a bit of clarity here.

I am asked to verify if the below statements are true or false:

1) $x^2 - a^2 = (b-iy)(b+y)$

2) The arguments differ by a multiple of $2\pi$

For 1) This is false as two complex numbers are identical iff $z_1 - z_2 = 0$ which in this instance it's given that $z_1 = z_2$ and from here I solve by splitting the real and imaginary numbers a part. A bit of simple algebra as follows:

$(x + iy) - (a + ib) = 0$
$ x + iy - a -ib = 0$
$x - a = -iy + ib$
$x - a = ib - iy$
$x - a = i(b - y)$

For 2) Surely this cannot differ by a multiple of $2π$ as $x + iy = a + ib$ and therefore $\theta = \arg (x + iy) = \arg (a + ib) $?

Thanks

Comment: If $z_1 = z_2$, wouldn't you have that x = a and y = b?

Comment: Yes I think you are right. As I understand I should equate the Re and Im parts separately. Is it correct though to have solved what they've given me in the way I've illustrated in my question and then equate the parts separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first statement, I'd say that a simpler argument for it to be false is that the RHS isn't zero (because of the $i$), while the LHS is.

For the second, think of complex numbers in their polar form $re^{i\phi}$; an argument of $\phi + 2\pi n$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ instead of just $\phi$ doesn't change anything - it is just a full rotation in the complex plane, so technically their argument can differ by a multiple of $2 \pi n$ and still be the same.

Comment: This makes sense. Plain and simple. Thanks